# In Tortuga Team’s Spaceland, what determines when turrets appear?

Tags: spaceland

I’m playing Spaceland’s first level that has turrets and drones. The turrets emerge from the floor, and when this happens seems to be based on player positions, but it doesn’t seem straightforward. I am struggling to predict this.

What’s the rule for when a turret emerges? (Any other tips for fighting or avoiding turrets?)

Comment: My current best guess is that there are hard-coded trigger tiles, like those that trigger enemies to spawn. I don’t think any markings on the floor, etc., show these points.